# How to write a regular expression to get text inside XML tags?

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that would return the text inside some  XML tags. For instance if I had a file with this format

```
<name>Joe Blog</name>
<email>abc@sample.com</email>
<address>123 sample st</address>
```

How would I extract the text for address field?

Any help with this would be appreciated.
thanks,

Comment: Choose a language you want to use. Why won't you just use a library that lets you parse your xml code with ease?

Comment: I recommend you to read this great answer to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Just waiting until someone pastes a link to that XHTML answer... (Edit: Oh, wait, there it goes.)

Comment: @Tomalak I'm sorry, but I couldn't disagree more. Did the question asked for a XML handler? For all we know, the XML file may be a text file in a local environment, with requirements just as simple (and quick). Why in heaven would someone need a full blown XML parser to deal with that? (Edit: I expected exactly the obvious, that someone would paste a link to that answer just because the words regex and xml/html were in the question. My point is still the same: Exactly from the way he asks, the requirements are probably simple, the enviroment is probably simple. Why a parser?)

Comment: @acdcjunior XML parser are very smart and are included in for example recent PHP versions by default. They use objects and are easy to use. You have so much more power with them.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I'm sure they are. A simple XPath processor would do the trick ([here's an online version](http://goo.gl/kS14hs)). The point is there is no point in assuming the OP has a very complicated system and wants a super-adaptable solution that regex can't work with. Even worse, that link helps nothing, it fails to even to explain why regex shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Tomalak "a text file in a local environment" is just "a file with in my notepad++". It makes a difference because why search for a parser (as easy as it could be, I just showed in my comment above), when it can be a "cannon to kill a fly"? Why paste a link to a poor-formatted joke instead of asking for clarification? This just happens **all the time**.

Comment: @Tomalak That's exactly the point! Where did you see *"I'm trying to parse this XML file with regex and so..."*? For all we know, he's just trying to find a string in a file that happens to have XML notation. The linked answer is famous because it is a joke, and that's it. The very newbies people think would profit from it wouldn't understand a thing from that cluttered bag of senseless words. And what's up with the random insult there? Where did I say "I think you can parse XML files with regex"? Did you understand anything I wrote at all?!

Comment: @Tomalak And how come *"Use a parser, this may be one time thing, but it's so much is better, you have to use it"* a better assumption than *"it is a simple case"*? How can posting a link to a, aw, *satire* (that does refers to memes - made by Yoda, who cares? - and is [as helpful as posting a link to another meme](http://bit.ly/SNvebk)) be better? I never said regexes are good to parse x/html, what I said it that answer useless and pops out **every single time**, despite being of no help at all. Why not saying, "hey, that could be done. But you [may wanna think twice](http://bit.ly/9Y0rpe)."

Comment: @Tomalak There is a long run? Assumption. Odds in your favor? Assumption. Right(assumption) tool at your disposal? Assumption. Regexes arent the wrong tool, simply because we can't infer what's the task before time. And that answer doesnt push any bit in the right direction. It is funny for those who already know what a CFG is, and just them. Just read the last couple paragraphs from[the post I suggested](http://codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html),will you? If even after that you still disagree, then you win: I'll paste that answer and suggest a parser from now on.

Comment: @Tomalak Great, glad your phase is over. Hopefully someday you'll also realize that going all the way to the other end is just as wrong - a behavior just as blind as the very one you bash (the thought that regex will parse anything, anytime). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This expression will capture the address value

`<address>(.*?)<\/address>`

[image]

and place it into the first capture group

## Example

**Sample Text**

```
<name>Joe Blog</name>
<email>abc@sample.com</email>
<address>123 sample st</address>
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = <address>123 sample st</address>
[0][1] = 123 sample st
```

## However

Most langages have a html parsing tool, for example you could do this in PHP by using:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_here);
$addresses= $dom->getElementsByTagName('address');
foreach($addresses as $address) {
    $address = $address->innertext;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: how do you make so nice graphs of regular expressions?

Comment: I make those from http://www.debuggex.com/ you simply paste your expression in and it shows the diagram

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to write your own or can you use tinyxml2?

If using tinyxml2 without a SAX parser and you know the document, try something like:

```
/* ------ Example 2: Lookup information. ---- */    
{
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile( "dream.xml" );

    // Structure of the XML file:
    // - Element "PLAY"      the root Element, which is the 
    //                       FirstChildElement of the Document
    // - - Element "TITLE"   child of the root PLAY Element
    // - - - Text            child of the TITLE Element

    // Navigate to the title, using the convenience function,
    // with a dangerous lack of error checking.
    const char* title = doc.FirstChildElement( "PLAY" )->FirstChildElement( "TITLE" )->GetText();
    printf( "Name of play (1): %s\n", title );

    // Text is just another Node to TinyXML-2. The more
    // general way to get to the XMLText:
    XMLText* textNode = doc.FirstChildElement( "PLAY" )->FirstChildElement( "TITLE" )->FirstChild()->ToText();
    title = textNode->Value();
    printf( "Name of play (2): %s\n", title );
}
```

If you want to use a SAX parser, tinyxml2 supports that mode as well.  For example code, head over to cocos2d-x and look at the CCSAXParser class which calls and subclasses tinyxml2 to parse almost any XML file.

Source: [tinyXML2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/)
        [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/)